# getting the COUNT value depending on the subqueries

Tags: mysql, sql, database

```
SELECT
    salesman_id,
    COUNT(sale_id)
FROM
    Commission
GROUP BY
    salesman_id
HAVING
    salesman_id IN (select... *subqueries*
```

COUNT(sale_id) gives me the number of sale_ids **regardless of the subqueries**,
although i want the number of sale_ids **after** the subqueries are done. how come this is not the case for COUNT, and how can i fix it?

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NGeDp.jpg)

[what i get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v4ezS.jpg)

what i want:

```
1 | 2
6 | 1
```

Comment: You would need to have a `where` clause that has some limit on the `sale_id` or some column other than the one you are grouping on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to limit the results that your query deals with then you need to do that in the `WHERE` clause.

The `HAVING` clause is filtering that happens **after** aggregates have been performed.

Try moving your subqueries to the `WHERE` clause instead.

Answer (score 0):

thanks guys, it works!

here is how:

removed `having`, moved `group by` to the end

```
WHERE 
    sale_id IN (select... *subqueries*
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT
    salesman_id,
    COUNT(sale_id)
FROM
    Commission
WHERE 
    salesman_id IN (select... *subqueries*)
GROUP BY
    salesman_id
```